# How to find the time taken by a kafka consumer to consume all messages from topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have to log the time taken by a consumer in spring kafka. As the kafkaListener method execute for each messages, putting a logger over there does not work. Also sometimes a few messages are getting lost and not consumed by consumer. Where should I put logger to find out the time elasped since the consumer starts. The consumer does not exit or shutdown, its polling indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `idleEventInterval` container property and use an `ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerIdleEvent>` bean (or an `@EventListener` method) to receive these events.

The events are published every `idleEventInterval` and contain an `idleTime` property which is the time since we last received a message.

For the start time, you can see the `partitions assigned` log message or just use the time the container was `start()`ed.

Comment: The application has other cron jobs and kafka consumers. I can not bring down the containers in production. Can I set a listener for a specifice producer or consumer, specifically for when it starts producing or consuming messages ?

Comment: ? I didn't suggest "bringing down the containers". The event contains the `id` of the listener which can be used in a condition on the `@EventListener`; see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#event-consumption). There is no "starting to consume" event; that will happen when the application starts (if there are existing topics). You will have to track the start time in the listener itself, when the first record arrives.